# Is there any way to imbed code in a constructor that will run after all the subclass(es)'s constructor code?

Tags: java, class, constructor, subclassing

Just what the title says.

Suppose I have created a class which I wish to leave open for subclassing. Now also supposed that I have some code which I wish to mandatorily execute as part of said class (and all it's subclasses') construction process. **But**, I don't want this code to be executed at the beginning of the construction process, I want to be certain that it is always executed at the very end of it. i.e. **after** all the code that is imbedded in the subclasses' constructor opperations.

I suspect that this is a problem without an answer, but on the off chance that it isn't, can anybody offer any assistance?

Comment: @Compass `super(...)` (and `this(...)`) can only appear on the first line of a constructor.

Comment: It's too early I'm gonna get my coffee =.=

Comment: You have no control over subclasses.  It's up to the subclass author's discretion.

Comment: No, there is no way to enforce this. Think about how you can design your class in a different way, so that you don't need this. This is related to the [call super anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super).

Comment: The only way to do it is to explicitly invoke a method after construction.

Comment: Tell all the people that will write subclasses to invoke `finishInit()` at the end of their constructors and that's about it. But as @AndyTurner said, `super()` can only be the first line of a constructor, and you want it being last which simply isn't going to happen easily..

Comment: Well, currantly I am building a class that tables data with a user being able to assign IDs to blocks of data. But the class also allows for "reserved names" which users aren't aloud to use. I want this list of reserved names to be locked in during the construction phase, with subclasses able to add to the list of names they want reserved. But presumably, within these constructors the class will also create the "untouchable"  data objects it wants to occupy these reserved slots.

Comment: no, wait, the wiki link says it just fine - implement the `abstract doFirst()` placeholder method in the superclass which all subclasses must implement, and be sure to call `doFirst()` in your superclass's constructor. That way the subclass can put whichever code it wants there and it will always be performed before the superclass's code as it will be invoked at the start of the superclass's constructor, and subclasses constructors can just fall down to `super();` You basically delegate the constructor responsibility to the `doFirst()` method, if possible.

Comment: Are constructors synchronized? If so, maybe I could have the superclass constructor create a thread that synchronizes on the class (i.e. blocks), and will then in theory execute it's code before any other thread can do anything to it as soon as the construction process is finished?

Comment: @Cambot ["note that constructors cannot be synchronized"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: Seems like you're trying to do too much work in the constructor (both superclass and subclass). Have you considered using a Builder pattern to pull all that work out of the constructor?

Comment: @AndyTurner Same article says that only the thread creating the object _should_ have access to it while it's being constructed. But does that mean that only that constructor thread is permitted access to that object until construction is complete? In other words, if another thread tries to synchronize on the object while it's being constructed, that thread will be blocked until construction is complete?

Comment: Read "should" as in "you are not prevented from doing it, but we've made it sufficiently hard that you might take the hint that you ought to find an alternative". Knock yourself out if you want to do it like this, but it sounds like you are just creating an appalling mess.

Answer (score -1):

Can you setup your parent class like this?

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public Parent() {
         initialize();
         postConstruct();
    }

    // Children's initialization logic
    protected abstract initialize();

    private final postConstruct() {
         // Code after initialization
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't invoke subclass methods in constructors. Not to mention that this precludes the use of `final` fields in your subclasses; and you can't define `initialize` on all of the subclasses in the chain.